# Splash-screen with alpha channels transparency/opacity in WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, transparency, opacity, splash-screen

How to implement a splash-screen using an image with alpha channels transparency/opacity in WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Per Pixel Alpha Blend in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/perpxalpha_sharp.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of shape your image is. Is it something you can draw using code? If so you could set the forms draw region to a shape, like this:

```
yourForm.Region = new Region(someShape);
```

The shape can for example be a polygon with the same shape as your image.

Comment: I would like to use any PNG image with 8-bit alpha transparency. Could you remember some earlier Adobe Acrobat Reader?